# CompositeConfiguration in log4j2 using springboot

Tags: java, spring-boot, log4j2

I am working in spring boot project and I stuck in an issue. Following is the problem.

I have two log4j2 configuration file. Log4j2-1.yml and Log4j2-2.yml. Log4j2-1.yml consist the common configuration to avoid repetition duplicate configuration while Log4j2-2.yml consists application specific log config. I need to use these two log4j2 configuration in my application at same time. Please help me to configure these files in my application.\

I tried log4j2.configurationFile also but could not succeed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Spring Boot has a custom logging configuration process that occurs just after the Log4j2 automatic configuration (its exact logic is in [`Log4j2LoggingSystem`](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/blob/main/spring-boot-project/spring-boot/src/main/java/org/springframework/boot/logging/log4j2/Log4J2LoggingSystem.java) and is documented in [Core Features](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/features.html#features.logging)). You can analyze the process by setting `-Dlog4j2.debug=true`.

To create a composite configuration you need to use two Spring Boot properties (cf. [core properties](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/application-properties.html#appendix.application-properties.core)):

```
logging.config=classpath:Log4j2-1.yml
logging.log4j2.config.override=classpath:Log4j2-2.yml
```